# how to detect sql data changes to refresh cache data?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

how to detect sql data changes to refresh cache data?i have cache algorith . i know caching . But i want to need some special usage to detect any changes in sql. How to make it below?BUT I NEED some advice and performance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the the SqlCacheDependency Class.

ASP.NET allows you to use the SqlCacheDependency class to create a cache item dependency on a table or row in a database. When a change occurs in the table or in a specific row, the item that has a dependency is invalidated and removed from the cache. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178604.aspx